# Why isn't my footer extending on both ends?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble trying to set my footer to full width. I think its something with the columns but I'm not sure how to fix this. How do I fill the left and right ends of my footer?

html:

```
<footer class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="copyrightText">
      <p class="col-sm-4"><a href='../credit/index.html'>&copy; Justin Sanchez</a></p>
        <ul class="col-sm-8">
          <li class="col-sm-1">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/anothernameforbox/">
              <img src="img/instalogo.png" type="button"></li></a>
          <li class="col-sm-1">
            <a href="https://linkedin.com/in/justin-emmanuel-o-sanchez/">
              <img src="img/linklogo.png"></li></a>
          <li class="col-sm-1">
            <a href="https://github.com/anothernameforbox">
              <img src="img/gitlogo.png"></li></a>
          <li class="col-sm-1">
            <a href="mailto:sanchezjustin6039@gmail.com">
              <img src="img/mailicon.png"></li></a>
          </ul>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:
    /*footer*/

```
footer {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: Azure;
  background-size: auto;
}

footer p {
  font-size: 15px;
}

footer .col-lg-12 {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

footer ul {
  list-style: none;
}

footer li img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1) use class `.container-fluid` instead of class `.container`.*

**OR**

*2) Change style for class `.container` like this:*

```
.container {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/84yp1nns/1/)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is you use `.container` class for the footer. Use `.container-fluid` for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.